# Windows 8.1 file system problems

Tags: windows

I'm having an issue with my files being stuck it seems.
The Windows explorer shows the file's metadata correctly on 1/14 (but the contents of the files are dated 1/5).
The open file dialog box shows the file's metadata incorrectly on 1/5.

Basically they are all the old version (even though they have been updated) on 1/5.

But Windows explorer shows them as being updated on 1/14 which is correct except the contents of the file are not up to date.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

This was a test we did. We copied one of the files from the folder to the desktop.  The source is on the right (`<directory>`) and destination on the left (desktop).

We can see that the meta data is not right.  The modified and access are not what they should be.

FYI and maybe this is the cause/reason.  The 1/5 date is when I updated from Windows 8 to 8.1 . This is the first time since then I've had to use these files and so I didn't notice the issue until now.

Comment: Did you run `chkdsk /x c:` yet?

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the problem.  we had to run the application as administrator which updated the file contents.  also seems to have fixed the meta data problem